# Stucked to Black Screen After installing Ubuntu 20.04 , an underscore is blinking for a long term

Tags: boot, 20.04

I'd just installed ubuntu 20.04 and after 1 day it's stuck at black screen after booting. An underscore is blinking on the top corner ...

There are many solutions regarding ubuntu 16, 18 but I'm new in ubuntu 20 Is there any change?

Answer (score 10):

I've fix this just few minutes ago. It was due to Nvidia driver.
After going into recovery mode and opened the root terminal.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`
and then
`sudo reboot`
for rebooting the ubuntu.
It rebooted with the Xorg graphics.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 I still see the blinking cursor instead of the login screen.

Comment: After literally spending a day, this trick worked. Many many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to switch to a terminal by pressing together [Ctrl], [Alt] and [F1]. If this is working, then there should be a login screen where you can login with your username and password. From thereon you can try to gather some informations.

One good source is the systemlog:

```bsh
journalctl -xe
```